# How to make clean URLs in Yii2 framework using .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii2

I am trying make clean url for my website developed using Yii2 framework using .htaccess only. I know that i can use urlmanager class of Yii2. But due to some specific reasons I can't use it and wanted make clean url using .htaccess only.

I wanted to convert the following url:
   Url = 'http://localhost:8090/index.php?r=site%2Fcontact'
 To
  Url = 'http://localhost:8090/contact'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Never even tried to do that, but you only want one controller?

Comment: no I want to do it for all controllers.

Comment: Then you obviously need it to be localhost:8090/site/contact. But as long as a you can't edit yii files, this is not a yii issue. Try reading the apache .htaccess documentation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to change urlManager component in you yii2 app config:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
]
```

**showScriptName** will remove index.php from URL format

**enablePrettyUrl** will provide pretty URL format, like "http://localhost/contant" you wanted)

Secondly, you need to set URL rewriting rule in you host configuration. Example for .htaccess (Apache):

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

You can read more in [Yii2 documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#using-pretty-urls%20Yii2%20documentation)